# HTML Grid of widgets over content without blocking

Tags: html, css, css-grid

This is quite a tough case to explain, so I appreciate your patience.

I want to have a grid of widgets, dynamically displayed and relatively positioned so I could place them dynamically where I want. These widgets will sit in front of the main content of the page. The user should be able to interact with them and the content behind too (click, type, etc).

My problem is that I need for these widgets to sit inside a CSS `grid` container to achieve my goal, but I don't want the container to sit in front of the main page content blocking it, which is what happens every time I try to solve this issue. I tried negative `z-index` for the container, I tried playing with other elements' `z-index`, but to no avail.

Here's an image to demonstrate the result I want. I could not come up with any usable HTML/CSS as of yet sadly.

[image: Rough drawing to explain the idea]

Comment: Please checkout [ask].

Comment: The problem with the question is that it is a opinion-based-question. The reason being is that have not provided an attempt at your problem. Additionally, the way that the question is written, is essentially asking us to write the solution for you.

Comment: @MarceloPaco I tried to explain the problem as much as I can. I have researched and attempted solutions for more than 2 weeks before asking here. I could not come up with any remotely working example sadly. I find it hard to see how this question is opinion-based, as I have a specific issue that I am trying to solve. Anyway, I will try to include minimal code examples in the question, if that makes it better.

Comment: Have you investigated pointer-events?

Comment: @AHaworth I have not. Do you think it could be useful on the widget container?

Comment: @AHaworth your answer is exactly what I need! Please add it as an answer below so I could mark this question as solved :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW, **@A Haworth** got the answer in the comments section.

Here's a simple implementation that solves my problem.

```js
let i = 0;
function clicking() {
  document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = `Text changed: i = ${i++}!`;
}
```

```css
html {
  height: 100vh;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background: aqua;
  gap: 1rem;
}

nav {
  text-align: center;
  writing-mode: sideways-lr;
  background: gold;
  padding: 1rem;
}

main {
  flex: 1;
  background: teal;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  pointer-events: none;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repear(6, 1fr);
  gap: 1rem;
}

.item {
  background: orange;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  pointer-events: all;
}

#item1 {
  grid-column: 1 / span 1;
  grid-row: 1 / span 1;
}

#item2 {
  grid-column: 1 / span 1;
  grid-row: 2 / span 4;
}

#item3 {
  grid-column: 5 / span 2;
  grid-row: 6 / span 1;
}

#item4 {
  grid-column: 6 / span 1;
  grid-row: 1 / span 1;
}

#item5 {
  grid-column: 3 / span 2;
  grid-row: 1 / span 1;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <nav>This is the sidebar.</nav>
  <main>
  <div class="content">
    <h3>Content</h3>
    <article>
      <p id="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      <button onclick="clicking()">Click me!</button>
    </article>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <div id="item1" class="item">Item 1</div>
    <div id="item2" class="item">Item 2 <button>I'm clickable too!</button></div>
    <div id="item3" class="item">Item 3</div>
    <div id="item4" class="item">Item 4</div>
    <div id="item5" class="item">Item 5</div>
  </div>
  </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

if widgets and content does not intersect each other visually, and they dont, as I see, why place widgets in its own contianer? place them together with content. such way includes "dynamically displayed and relatively positioned" chances.

if you still want different containers for content and widgets, both left-side and right-side widgets must have its own container, and with content must be wrapped in parent element, which will determine their positions by `grid` or `flex`

Comment: My content could be different in each page, that's why I tried to make the widget container an independent component. Your second idea is quite useful and I will attempt it, but I fear that the empty areas under the widgets would block anything behind them. Thank you.

Comment: with `flexed` parent, unused empty spaces from `child` elements can be so to say trimmed. anything rather than `stretch` for `aligh-items`/`justify-content` will do the trick